# What is the best way to change the background color of any thing in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way to change the color of background of anything in bootstrap?
Such as heading, font color, panel heading etc.

Comment: You probably want to try something like http://stylebootstrap.info/ or  http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/twitter-bootstrap-themeroller.html to generate this for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either [customise](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) bootstrap before you use it or use an overriding stylesheet of your own.